# How can I get MySQL workbench to always show the result grid?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql5

When I execute a `SELECT` query in the MySQL workbench, the result grid appears.  Then, when I execute an `UPDATE`, the grid disappears.  Then when I run a `SELECT` again to view the changes, it reappears.

This is incredibly annoying and causes the screen to constantly fluctuate up and down.  Is there any way I can give the result grid a permanent home somewhere?

Even if it just stayed put somewhere and was cleared of data when the `UPDATE` ran, that would be perfect.

Comment: I had this problem (Results Grid would never appear anymore) on macOS 10.14.5 with Workbench 6.3.9.CE. Upgrading to Workbench 8.0.17.CE fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it. Pin the results tab to force it to remain and be unaffected by UPDATE statements. Do that by right-clicking the result tab and choose "Pin Tab" from the context-menu, or left-click the little pin icon to toggle it. Now, execute your other queries and then refresh the pinned tab (there's a "refresh" icon in the result grid's menu).

Comment: Just about as perfect as I could expect!  Thank you so much.  Knew there had to be some way.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Mysql Workbench preferences.
In Fonts, change de Resultset Grid font to Arial 11.

Its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the result grid in MySQL Work bench by clicking on the table you find the symbol with grid, if you click on that you can find it below the sql editor.
It worked for me in windows 10